# Criar/manipular arquivo dentro de um diretório diferente do que está o main.cpp

Tags: c++

Isto funciona, cria um arquivo e coloca o que eu quero dentro dele:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    ofstream arquivo;
    arquivo.open("arquivo.txt");
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("linha1");
    v.push_back("linha2");
    v.push_back("linha3");
    if(arquivo.is_open()){
        for(auto n: v) { arquivo << n << endl; }
    }
}
```

Mas isto não funciona, se eu quero criar um novo arquivo dentro de uma pasta chamada "pasta", ele não dá erro, só não cria o arquivo. Faz absolutamente nada:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    ofstream arquivo;
    arquivo.open("pasta/arquivo.txt");
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("linha1");
    v.push_back("linha2");
    v.push_back("linha3");
    if(arquivo.is_open()){
        for(auto n: v) { arquivo << n << endl; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro está na hora de abrir um arquivo *inexistente* para gravação. A chamada do método `ofstream::open()` cria um novo arquivo caso ele não exista, porém, [não cria diretórios!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682148/how-to-create-directories-automatically-using-ofstream?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Você pode incluir um tratamento mais elaborado de erros usando a macro [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) da biblioteca padrão `cerrno` em conjunto com a função [`std::strerror()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) da biblioteca padrão `cstring`.

Vejamos como entender o erro:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( void ) {
    ofstream arquivo;
    vector<string> v;

    arquivo.open("diretorio/arquivo.txt");

    if(!arquivo.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Erro abrindo o arquivo para gravacao: " << std::strerror(errno) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    v.push_back("linha1");
    v.push_back("linha2");
    v.push_back("linha3");

    for(auto n: v) { arquivo << n << endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 teste.cpp -o teste
```

Saída:

```
Erro abrindo o arquivo para gravacao: No such file or directory
```

Uma alternativa não padrão, porém elegante para resolver seu problema é usar a biblioteca [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html), que possui uma função chamada [`create_directories()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories), vejamos:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main( void ) {
    ofstream arquivo;
    vector<string> v;

    boost::filesystem::create_directories("diretorio" );

    arquivo.open("diretorio/arquivo.txt");

    if(!arquivo.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Erro abrindo o arquivo para gravacao: " << std::strerror(errno) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    v.push_back("linha1");
    v.push_back("linha2");
    v.push_back("linha3");

    for(auto n: v) { arquivo << n << endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ g++ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -std=c++11 teste.cpp -o teste
```